# SQL Server Sync: push SQL Server changes to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, synchronization

I have a SQL Server on a VLAN that I have read permissions to and I need a SQL Server instance on an external network to be synced. I only have read permissions and our partner won't allow us to configure replication so that's not an option. On top of all that because it's on a vlan the external SQL Server can't connect to it directly.

I think my best bet now is simply to write an application (most likely in C#) that will detect changes and push them to the external SQL Server. This approach doesn't seem ideal.

Are there any out of the box ways to do this or any tried and true methods?

Comment: Plenty of tools do that, check out Redgate and ApexSQL

Comment: What about log shipping? Even if you do it the poor man's way with a batch job to just copy them over? It won't be *sync'd* per say, but close if the tlog backups are pretty frequent.

Comment: I've given some thought to log shipping. Seems like the only lead I was able to find. 

Can Redgate PUSH changes/transations to a remote SQL server? If it can do that I think I've found my solution